# How do I prevent RSpec from using "Rspec.describe... " and "type: ..." in generated specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3, rails-generators

Since upgrading to RSpec 3 my generated spec files contain `RSpec.describe` instead of just `describe`, and explicitly include the type with e.g. `:type => :model`. For example, here's the model spec file that was just generated for a class called "Plan":

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Plan, :type => :model do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

I'd rather have it look like this (note the changes on line 3):

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Plan do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

... the "type" call seems especially redundant because I have the line `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` in `rails_helper`.

How can I make RSpec generate spec files which look like my 2nd example? I don't want to have to manually edit it every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the template in the [rspec-rails github repo](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/model/templates/model_spec.rb) you can see there is no option to do this via config variables. But you should be able to customize it by just creating a file in your `lib/generators/rspec/model/templates/`  that is called `model_spec.rb` for creating a custom generator for your models. It's just an erb template as you can see in the link above:

```
require 'rails_helper'

<% module_namespacing do -%>
RSpec.describe <%= class_name %>, :type => :model do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
<% end -%>
```

You should be easily able to customize any generator that Rspec defines with this approach. Yoe can even add extra things. Futher Info is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates). Hope this helpes you :)